# Are my assassins' experience levels bugged?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

I'm confused... In Assassins Creed: Revelations I have lots of assassins which I've sent off on missions, however their XP to next level is less than their current XP (i.e, XP of 13k, next level 3.8k).  I've noticed this on more than one assassin and they all seem to be stuck at level 10.

Any idea how to fix this so the assassins can be the correct level to reflect their XP?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assassins can only level up past level 10 under certain circumstances.  I believe they must become leaders of a den first.  I believe to get to the highest level (Master Assassin, level 15 if I recall) you must do the second part of their den's memory.  When they're ready, you'll get a notification that an assassin is "ready for more training."

Since there are a limited number of dens, many of your assassins will stop leveling at level 10.  Experience is still tracked up to the Master Assassin rank, presumably so that in case you promoted them to den leader, that experience wouldn't go to waste.

I ended up having several of my 'non-den leader' assassins have more experience than my den leader assassins, which meant that I had to continue training the den leaders in order to unlock the Master Assassin/den leader memories.  Let that be a lesson - if you've got to pick a new den leader, try to pick an assassin that is the closest to the highest level, so you unlock the related mission faster.

Comment: ["status-by-design"]

Comment: This is exactly right - only den leaders (limited to 7, one per den) can level past level 10.

Comment: All the right assassins are now level 15.. thanks =)

Answer (score -1):

Considering I only have 7 master Assassin's in my cities I think yes only den masters can level up past 10

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! This doesn't add much to the already accepted answer.

Comment: Try to give an answer that doesn't reiterate a previous answer and one with actual explanation instead of basically saying: "yes that does seem to be the case".